# matlab assign vector of values to vector of variables

Tags: matlab, variables, vector

I have a set of 33 variables, I am optimizing only a subset of them ("P"). I want to automatically reassign the optimized P every iteration, and I'm trying to do so like this:

```
j=size(P);
for i=1:j
    Q=[c25;c26;c27;c28;];
    Q(i)=P(i);
end
```

I think its an easy fix, but matlab forums are down right now and I'm on a tight schedule :) I have tried declaring Q outside the loop, and declaring each variable with a value (c25=1, for ex) and then trying to re-declare them with the loop to their new optimized values, but the loop was not overwriting them.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you have 33 variables which are so closely connected, that you can perform actions on all of them. Reconsider your variable creation process.

Comment: Your explanations are unclear. What is P, a structure ? Give an example.

Comment: I dont understand the question?

Comment: P is a vector of variables which i am optimizing/curve fitting to some data, its P=[c25,c26,c27,c28] for example. normally I reassign the optimized value each iteration like: c25=P(1), c26=P(2), etc. but its very tedious as after I finish optimizing one subset of variables, I will need to optimize another set of them, so Im trying to find a way to make it more efficient

Comment: for clarification, the curve fit function takes P and passes it to my evaluation function, which evaluates my equations given P. The output from those equations is passed back to the curve fit function, which compares it to the data, and then modifies P, and passes it back to the evaluation function, until it reaches some minimum.

Comment: So why do you need `P=[c25,c26,c27,c28]` and not something like `P(25) =  ...`?